# Does wp_insert_post validate the input?

Tags: validation, wp-insert-post

If I use the wp_insert_post in a plugin, will I have to check the content for SQL injection problems and XSS or will the wp_insert_post function do this for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer; **absolutely**.

`wp_insert_post()` will only SQL escape the content. Use the [KSES library](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/kses.php) & [wp_kses()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) to filter out the nasties, or `esc_html()` to escape *all* HTML.

Most importantly, check out [the codex on data validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) (read: sanitization).

**A Note On KSES:** Use [wp_filter_kses()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_kses) or `wp_kses_data()` to apply the same KSES rules as post comments. The subtle difference between the two is the former expects data escaped with slashes (and returns the same), whilst the latter does not.

WordPress (bizarrely) **enforces magic quotes**, so `$_POST`, `$_GET` (and the like) will have escape slashes added by default.

**A Note On wp_insert_post():** This function also expects the data array to have slashes added, so you'll need to sanitize it with [add_magic_quotes()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_magic_quotes) if that's not the case.

**Update:** And put in practice;

```
$_POST['post_title'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['post_title'] ); // also expects & returns slashes
$_POST['post_content'] = wp_filter_kses( $_POST['post_content'] );

$post_ID = wp_insert_post( $_POST );

// add to the fun - wp_update_post() will add slashes if $postdata is an object!
$update = ( object ) stripslashes_deep( array( 'ID' => $post_ID ) + $_POST );
$update->post_title .= ' Updated!';
wp_update_post( $update )
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. So if I understood you right, if the data passed to the wp_insert_post comes from $_POST, then I don't have to do anything because escape slashes are added by default. Am I correct?

Comment: Yup - I posted a snippet for clarity :)